# What is the meaning of "Expressions" & "BeanExpression" in Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

As per the official Camel document, *"Expressions and Predicates can then be used to create the various Enterprise Integration Patterns in the DSL or Xml Configuration like the Recipient List.
To support dynamic rules Camel supports pluggable Expression strategies using a variety of different Languages."*

Could anyone please elaborate or explain it in plain English?

Answer (score 1):

Expressions are used to return any value from the current message exchange. An example of an expression would be using Xpath to retrieve a node from the XML in the body of a message. When the documentation says pluggable strategies, its essentially saying you can use different approaches / languages, including Groovy, JavaScript, etc. A predicate is a **specialized expression** used to evaluate a condition on the message exchange. It is similar to the condition you would find in a Java if statement. A predicate always returns a Boolean value.

Here's a code example where a message is coming from ActiveMQ and based on the XPath predicate, the message gets routed to another queue.

```
from("activemq:queue:ORDER_ITEM_PROCESSING").
   choice().
      when().xpath("/o:Order/o:OrderType/o:FulfillmentCenter = '" + 
            com.pluralsight.orderfulfillment.generated.FulfillmentCenter.ABC_FULFILLMENT_CENTER.value()
            + "'", namespace).to("activemq:queue:ABC_FULFILLMENT_REQUEST")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah you can also view this as: expression = function that returns anything kind of object - eg java.lang.Object. predicate = function that returns a boolean.